# Power BI - Best practice importing big data?

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-datasource

I'm new in the BI field and I have to develop the BI of over 25 million records.

I'm using DirectQuery to import the data to PowerBi and to web. But the dashboard loading is too slow. And sometimes the dashboard won't load.

I'd like to know what's the best way to import big amount of data to PowerBI and to publish in the web after the fact.

DirectQuery, Analysis Service, what else?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why a direct query? That means you have to load all the data every time you connect.

Comment: Direct query doesn't import the data: the query gets run when you use Power BI. So the generated query might be slow, depending on how you've designed your model and what the queries for the dashboard are doing. What other modes have you tried or considered?

Answer (score -2):

you can do

> 1) make aggregation on data and reduce size of data.
>   2) bring only useful column only- that reduce size again
>   3) data is (real time/permutation -combination) only then use direct qry
>   4) if spark --you can connect to directly to spark